# Function of the Cache in FieldcacheImpl

Tags: jakarta-ee, solr, lucene, search-engine, lucene.net

I tried to analyse the FieldCacheImpl in Solr 3.5.0, can any one explain me or give me pointer to know what does the abstract Class Cache is performing upfront?

Thanks and Regards,

Jeyaprakash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in `FieldCache.java`, there are several different methods to load the fieldcache (getBytes, getInts, getStringIndex, getStrings, ...). This is why `FieldCacheImpl` maintains a `map (type -> cache)`.

Lucene segments are write-once and then read-only, so you want to load the field cache only once, and then always re-use the same instance. Cache is a helper class that helps achieve this: it is a wrapper around a `map (segment -> map (field -> fieldcache instance))`. (By fieldcache instance, I mean a `byte[]` for the `getBytes` method, a `String[]` for the `getStrings` method, ...)

- When a segment is not used anymore (if there is no more open reader using it), you want the GC to be able to reclaim the fieldcache, which is why this map is a [WeakHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html).
- There are different `Cache` implementations because the logic is not the same when loading (for example) a String cache and a StringIndex cache (see `Cache#createValue(AtomicReader, Entry, boolean)`).

Comment: Hi Adrien, I could understand what you have mentioned above, since my existing version is Solr 1.3.0 and I'm planning to mmigrate to Solr 3.5, so It would be of great help if you could differentiate the Cache class in both versions?

Comment: Hi Adrien, I could understand what you have mentioned above, since my existing version is Solr 1.3.0 and I'm planning to mmigrate to Solr 3.5, so It would be of great help if you could differentiate the Cache class in both versions?

Comment: These are essentially the same. However, you should know that Lucene is storing more and more data at the segment level, meaning that the recommandation now is to use the field cache only with atomic readers. See http://www.searchworkings.org/blog/-/blogs/uwe-says%3A-is-your-reader-atomic for more information about atomic readers and fieldcache.